# Uncaught Error: No define call for reveal

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

This what I did in `main.js` :

```
requirejs.config({
enforceDefine: true,
paths: {
    "jquery": "libs/jquery/jquery-min",
    "underscore": "libs/underscore/underscore-min",
    "backbone": "libs/backbone/backbone-min",
    "reveal":"libs/jquery/jquery.reveal"

},
shim: {
    "underscore": {
        deps: [],
        exports: "_"
    },
    "backbone": {
        deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    },
    "reveal": {
        exports: "Reveal"
    }

}
});
```

Uncaught Error: No define call for reveal
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine

Any idea what could be causing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the API for the [`enforceDefine` property](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html##config-enforceDefine). Your `reveal` shim does not specify jQuery as a dependency, and the extra property also requires you to export it properly:

```
"reveal": {
    deps: ["jquery"],
    exports: "jQuery.fn.reveal"
}
```

Comment: You save my day, Herman Tran! But could you tell me, how do you know `reveal` have to exports `jQuery.fn.reveal`? I tried to find it, but did not find this.

Comment: jQuery plugins register themselves with the [`jQuery.fn.extend()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/), so you can usually expect them to be exported as `jQuery.fn._plugin_name_`. There's also a more concrete example if you scroll a little further down in the [RequireJS `shim` doc](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).

Comment: Ohh.. Okay it makes sense now. Thank you very much.

Comment: No prob, glad I could help!